# ../golang/pkg/mod/github.com/wmentor/lemmas@v0.0.6/processor.go:72:9: undefined: tokens.Process

Tags: go

i installed [lib](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/wmentor/lemmas#section-readme)

tried to start example:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"

  "github.com/wmentor/lemmas"
)

func main() {

  txt := "Создать экспертную систему."

  processor := lemmas.New()

  processor.AddText(strings.NewReader(txt))

  processor.FetchResult(func(keyphrase string, weight float64) {
    fmt.Println(keyphrase, weight)
  })
}
```

but it didnt work. How to fix it?

A compiler returns:
`../golang/pkg/mod/github.com/wmentor/lemmas@v0.0.6/processor.go:72:9: undefined: tokens.Process`

I tried to surf source code, compare versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the problem is presence `-u` flag in installing command at the main page of lib. Just install lib as : `go get github.com/wmentor/lemmas`

[source](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561243/golang-pkg-mod-github-com-wmentor-lemmasv0-0-6-processor-go729-undefined/1561300#1561300)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with your code but with the dependency. `lemmas` is using `"github.com/wmentor/tokens"` and is expecting it to provide `tokens.Process(...)` function which it doesn't:

[image]

Quick solution would be to fork `lemmas` and either reimplement `AddText` or if you don't need it in your case - remove it. Better solution maybe fix and open a pull request to the lemmas .